# ASP.NET Core configure Middleware to block IP

Tags: asp.net-core, ip, middleware

I already configured Middleware to Block IP when I detect IP as a bot,
The main problem is that even though I send the status code as Too Many Request, the body is null (as below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDzzJ.png)

but it's still affect bad to my server (processor get high, with download/upload mb/s)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbL2m.png)

You guys have any solution
Thanks

Solution for blocking IP

Comment: You should probably then block the IP address at the network level(load balancer or firewall), if you don't want to affect server resources by blocking at app level.

Comment: Thank @DenisMicheal, do I apply IIS Webfarm Load Balance to solve the problem?
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/configuring-step-3-configure-iis-web-farm-load-balancing)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the IIS, it contains IP address and domain restrictions settings.

By using this setting, you could use its feature to deny ip address based on the number of request over a period of time.

More details about how to enable and use it,, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/) and below settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank @Brando Zhang, it's still affect my server resources

Comment: Have you modified the settings? Besides, this is the IIS level restrict to block the IP which means the request will still go to your server. If want to block it out of the server, maybe you should consider using some firewall or else.